# Why is my submit button not working on bootstrap models?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

The modal for my submit button does not pop-up (It does, but only for a split second) whenever I click on it. The purpose of the modal that is connected to the submit button is to make sure the user does not redirect to the next page whenever there are unfilled fields in the form (by using validation rules). I am using bootstrap, codeigniter4, and php. Can someone help me?

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<?php if (isset($validation)) :?>
                  
                   
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">The following fields are required </h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="text-danger">
        <?= $validation->listErrors()?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 

<?php endif;?>
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
<button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary me-2" id="submit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Submit</button>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: So what exactly happens instead of it opening the modal? `type="submit"` is likely to make it try and submit the form to the server and ignore any client-side instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to pop up the model if the user doesn't fill up all the details. The easiest way to achieve this is to first check if there are any validation errors. Something like:

```
<?php if($validation_errors){ ?>
<button type="button"class="btn btn-primary me-2" id="submit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Submit</button>
<?php }else{ ?>
<button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary me-2" id="submit">Submit</button>
<?php } ?>
```

more convenient would be using [bootstrap alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/).